# Excel vba: possible bug when creating a range as a sub-range of another range

Tags: excel, vba

I created the following sub to illustrate the problem simply. I assign the range A2:E10 of the active sheet to a range variable. Then, to another range variable, I assign the sub-range of this range, cells (1, 1) to (3, 3).

I would have expected that this would include the range A2 to C4 (since A2 is the first col, first row of the larger range). However, when I call the .Row method of each range's
first cell, I get different results: the larger range r returns "2", whereas the smaller range rSub returns "3".

(the .Row method returns the absolute row of the range it is called upon)

I would expect both these calls to return 2, as they should both refer to cell A2. Can anyone explain why this is not so?

*Edit: I have just altered the sub so that it calls the .Column method of each range's first cell, as it does the .Row method. This returns "1" for both ranges, as you might expect.

```
Sub test()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Range("A2:E10")

    MsgBox r.Cells(1).Row     '= 2

    Dim rSub As Range
    With r
        Set rSub = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(3, 3))
    End With

    MsgBox rSub.Cells(1).Row     '= 3
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Quite strange~

I got the same result from you code. I guess the result comes from the following code:

Set rSub = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(3, 3))

When I removed the dot before Range I got the result as we expected

Set rSub = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(3, 3)))

Anyway I have no idea why this happens.

Comment: I found that it also works if you remove the dots before "Cells" rather than the one before "Range". I would have thought doing so would force vba to use those cells belonging to the active sheet, rather than r or rSub.
I thought about it, and I think it uses the .Row and .Column values in calculating the ranges. So for .Cells(1, 1) of rsub, the Row value is 2. The start of the range is also 2. So it must do something like "CellRow - RangeStartRow + 1", hence it comes up with 3

Answer (score 0):

That is interesting.

I think that the .cells(3,3) inside the parentheses is resolving to an address, which basically acts like an offset inside the range.  Here's a simpler version that yields a similar result:

```
Sub test()
Dim r As Range
Dim rSub As Range

Set r = Range("A2")
Set rSub = r.Range(r.Cells(1).Address) '"A2"
Debug.Print rSub.Cells(1).Address
End Sub
```

The line  `Set rSub = r.Range(r.Cells(1).Address)` is equivalent to:

`Set rSub = r.Range("A2")` which resolves to "A3."

You can use addresses inside a range definition this way.  For example

```
`? Activesheet.Range("A10:A20").Range("A2").Address` yields `$A$11`
```

I realize that you didn't use "Address" anywhere in your code, but like I said, I think it resolves to an address.  In my sample, if I remove "Address" I get a runtime error.